# MongoDB - Realm (aggregation $search text) needs a role with search document-level permission to perform a $search

Tags: mongodb, realm, full-text-search, serverless

I'm trying to do a full-text query to my MongoDB using Realm as my Serverless Authenticator and functions-Server.
In Realm, I made a function that can be called from the client to do this query. The function looks like this:

```
exports = function( jobName,collection="jobs"){
  const agg = [
   {
    '$search': {
      'text': {
        'path': [
          'name', 'description'
        ],
        'query': jobName,
        'fuzzy': {}
       }
     }
   }
   ];
   var collectionObj = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("myDb").collection(collection);
   var result = collectionObj.aggregate(agg)
   return result;
};
```

If I run this function as a System User I get exactly what I want from the DB. But if I want to run the search as an Anonymous User I get the following error:

```
A role with a search document-level permission is required to perform a $search
```

So I went to my roles and I created a role called normal with document-level search permissions:
[User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zCVa.png)

The error is still happening and I have no clue where to keep looking. The Advanced Options in the User also show the search field turned to true:

```
  {
  "name": "normal",
  "apply_when": {},
  "insert": false,
  "delete": false,
  "search": true,
  "read": true,
  "fields": {
    "description": {},
    "name": {}
  },
  "additional_fields": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a way to use the full-text function through realm from a Client but it involves creating an open REST API. Instead of calling a function through the client we can create a REST API and return the search from that entry point. Karen Huaulme from MongoDB did something like that on her [Movie Tutorial](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/build-movie-search-application). This is really not the Answer I was hoping for but it is a nice workaround.